# Agreement of "être", "donner" in passé composé

Tags: accord, temps-grammatical, participe-passé

I'm only just starting to learn French and I'm having trouble understanding the conjugation of "être" and "donner" in the passé composé. I usually look up words in Collins dictionary online but I find there the following information which confuses me:

```
j'ai été
tu as été
il/elle a été
nous avons été
vous avez été
ils/elles ont été
```

The same pattern is used to conjugate "donner".

I wonder shouldn't it be rather like this?

```
elle a étée
nous avons étés
vous avez étés
elles ont étées
```

In analogy with how the past participle of "aller" conjugates (this is found in the same dictionary):

```
je suis allé
tu es allé
il/elle est allé/allée
nous sommes allés
vous êtes allés
ils/elles sont allés/allées
```

Are été and donné some kind of exceptions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The auxiliary used for the verb *être* is ***avoir***. Like for all other verbs that use *avoir* as an auxiliary the agreement of the past-participle is done with the direct object (only if it appears before the verb).

> Elle **a** pleuré. (no direct object)
>   Ils **ont** posé des questions. (direct object after the verb)
>   Les questions qu'ils **ont** posé**es**. (direct object before the verb)

For *aller* the auxiliary is ***être***, and in this case the agreement is done with the subject.

> Elle **est** allé**e** dans le jardin.
>   Ils **sont** venu**s** rapidement.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just to make the usage before "avoir" totaly clear for me (your third example sentence), if it were "La question" you would not change the verb, right? It would be "La question qu'ils ont posé"?

Comment: @Yaroslav: *La question qu'ils ont posé**e***. It's now singular but still feminine.

Answer (score 5):

French uses two auxiliaries for its compound tenses : *être* and *avoir*.
*être* is mostly associated with intransitive verbs, and all reflexive constructions:

- *Paul est parti* ('Paul has left') intransitive
- *Paul s'est vu dans le miroir* ('Paul saw himself in the mirror') reflexive

*avoir* is mostly associated with transitive verbs (and **never** used in reflexive constructions)

- *Paul a mangé* ('Paul ate') lexically transitive verb
- *Paul a été brave* ('Paul was brave') *être* selects *avoir* as an auxiliary even though it is not a transitive verb...

Now for the past participle agreement, French has only 3 cases:

1. Reflexive constructions behave exactly as if they selected *avoir*
2. with the *être* selection, the past participle agrees in gender and number with the subject argument
3. with the *avoir* selection, the past participle can agree in gender and number with the direct object if it is placed before the participle and it is not the clitic pronoun *en*

Examples:

- *être* agreement with the subject

  - *Paul est mort* vs *Marie est morte* vs *elles sont mortes*
  - *il est arrivé* vs *ils sont arrivés* vs *elle est arrivée* vs *elles sont arrivées*
- *avoir* agreement with the direct object on the left (except *en*)

  - *Marie a mangé des pommes* and *Marie a mis des robes rouges*
    direct object on the right => default agreement: M.SG
  - *Marie en a mangé* and *Marie en a mis des rouges* (**mises*)
    direct object = *en* => default agreement: M.SG
  - *Les pommes que Marie a mangées étaient bonnes* and *les robes que Marie a mises étaient jolies*
    direct object on the left => agreement in gender and number with the object: F.PL
- *reflexive and reciprocal constructions* => same as *avoir*

  - *Marie s'est écrit un post-it*
    direct object = *un post-it*
    direct object on the right => default agreement: M.SG
  - *Marie s'en est mis sur le col*
    direct object = *en* => default agreement: M.SG
  - *Marie s'est vue dans le miroir*
    direct object = *se*
    direct object on the left => agreement in gender and number with the object: F.SG
  - *Les roses que Marie s'est offertes sont jolies*
    direct object = *les roses*
    direct object on the left => agreement in gender and number with the object: F.PL

As mentioned by @Sifu, these are the rules for formal written French. Colloquially speaking the agreement is welcome but not realized with *avoir* most of the time. The proportion tends to be higher with *être*. In very formal context, some people tend to use what we could call hyper-corrected French and make mistaken agreements even with the *en* clitic...

Answer (score 2):

Actually it depends on the auxiliary verb.

- When you use "*être*" the past participle varies in terms of gender
  and number.
- With "*avoir*" the past participle is invariable.

Source (la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com) : [**être**](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/orthographe/l-accord-du-participe-passe-employe-avec-l-auxiliaire-etre-178.php), [**avoir**](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/orthographe/l-accord-du-participe-passe-employe-avec-l-auxiliaire-avoir-179.php)

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Comment: Actually, the past participle **is** variable with *Avoir*. Only on some circonstences.

Comment: @Sifu: Is it the case that Stéphane illustrates with "Les questions qu'ils ont posées." ?

Comment: @YaroslavFomenko You should really only worry about the rules that Stéphane stated, yes. There are precise rules and exceptions on that subject, but most of us, French natives, don't even half of them correctly.

Comment: @Sifu: Thank you!